# pandas creating a dataframe from mysql database

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, mysql-python

So I have been trying to create a dataframe from a mysql database using pandas and python but I have encountered an issue which I need help on.

The issue is when writing the dataframe to excel, it only writes the last row ie, it overwrites all the previous entries and only the last row is written. Please see the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import csv


with open('C:path_to_file\\extract_job_details.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        jobid = str(row[1])
        statement = """select jt.job_id ,jt.vendor_data_type,jt.id as TaskId,jt.create_time as CreatedTime,jt.job_start_time as StartedTime,jt.job_completion_time,jt.worker_path, j.id as JobId from dspe.job_task jt JOIN dspe.job j on jt.job_id = j.id  where jt.job_id = %(jobid)s"""",
        df_mysql = pd.read_sql(statement1, con=mysql_cn)
        try:
             with pd.ExcelWriter(timestr+'testResult.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
      df_mysql.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

         except pymysql.err.OperationalError as error:
            code, message = error.args
            mysql_cn.close()
```

Please can anyone help me identify where I am going wrong? 
PS i am a new to pandas and python.
Thanks Carlos

Comment: You defined `statement` but somehow you are passing `statement1` to the `pd.read_sql` function. Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do reading from disk and a database at the same time...

First, you don't need `csv` when you're already using Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path/to/input/csv")
```

Next you can simply provide a file path as an argument to `to_excel` instead of an `ExcelWriter` instance:

```
df.to_excel("path/to/desired/excel/file")
```

If it doesn't actually need to be an excel file you can use:

```
df.to_csv("path/to/desired/csv/file")
```